# Accessing variable in class by value of string

Tags: c#

I am making a text based adventure and want to have a `function` in my **player class** that increases a variable in the class by accepting a `string`(for the variable name ) and `int` (for the amount)

```
class player
{
  private int stat1 = 1;
  private int stat2 = 2; 
  public void statincrease(string name, int amount)
  {
    //variable called by string// += amount  
  }
  private void main()
  {
   player.statincrease(stat2,5);
  }
}
```

sorry if i have not explained my self very well,  but any help on this would much appreciated

Comment: It's certainly possible to do this via reflection, but it it REQUIRED that you do it? It's a pretty fragile, developer-unfriendly design if users of this class have to call a generic method to change a property, and they have to know the exact name of the property they want to change, spell it correctly, etc. There will be no intellisense for them. You might consider using public properties and/or methods on the class for changing values instead.

Comment: Why would you want to to it? can you explain more about the use-case? Maybe a dictionary<string, int> would fit better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can tell you're new at this so I'll be easy on you.

There are several ways to go about something like what you're asking.

My first suggestion is to make a method for each name you need, so instead of string name you have shieldStatIncrease(int amount); swordStatIncrease(int amount); etc.

If you don't want to do that then you can use if or switch statements

```
public void statincrease(string name, int amount)
{
    switch(name)
    {
         case "stat1":
            //Increase stat1
            break;
         case "stat2":
            //Increase stat2
            break; //etc...
    }
}
```

If this isn't what you're talking about then I apologize... Let me know and I'll adjust my answer.

Now if you're trying to get real technical you can use reflection to find the property name and adjust the variable for you... But I don't recommend that; especially not for a game because reflection has a little more overhead.

Answer (score 1):

This would be the recommended approach, which is not what you're asking for: create public properties that users can access and adjust. You can include some data validation in the property setter if you want to enforce that the value stays within some particular bounds:

```
class Player
{
    public int Stat1 { get; set; }
    public int Stat2 { get; set; }

    public Player()
    {
        Stat1 = 1;
        Stat2 = 2;
    }
}
```

Then the user of this class would do something like:

```
var player = new Player();
player.Stat2 += 5; // Increase Stat2 by 5
```

---

Alternatively, you could keep the members private and create a method that changes the values, though I think this is less common:

```
class Player
{
    private int stat1 = 1;
    private int stat2 = 2;

    public void AdjustStat2(int adjustmentIncrement)
    {
        stat2 += adjustmentIncrement;
    }
}
```

---

Finally, to answer your original question, you can have the user type in a string and do matching on the variable name, but that is a painful process for users of your class because they can't just type `Player.` and get an intellisense list of the properties they have access to:

```
class Player
{
    private int stat1 = 1;
    private int stat2 = 2;

    public void AdjustProperty(string propName, int adjustmentIncrement)
    {
        if (propName.Equals("stat1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            stat1 += adjustmentIncrement;
        }
        else if (propName.Equals("stat2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            stat2 += adjustmentIncrement;
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree this is a better formatted answer but I sensed, by the question, that he's just starting to learn and there is more excitement in creating than learning sometimes.. So, not to deafen the ears I tried to keep it simple. But, later maybe he'll come back and see the more desired approach and it will make better sense to him.  But up voted because I agree.